# ec2 bundling on AWS (Amazon Web Services)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I took an existing ec2 image that I had, made some changes and re-bundled it.

However, when I try to launch my new image it only lets me launch it as a Large instance -- not a small image.

What happened?  How can I fix it?

I made sure when calling ec2-bundle-vol to specify -r i386

Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get when you try to launch as a small instance?

Answer (score 2):

Did you re-bundle it as a 64-bit image? If so, you can't run it as a small image. Small images are 32-bit, while the smallest 64-bit image is m1.large.

Comment: How do you bundle as 64 versus 32?

Comment: From the EC2 docs:

ec2-bundle-vol -d /mnt -k /mnt/pk-HKZYKTAIG2ECMXYIBH3HXV4ZBZQ55CLO.pem -c /mnt/cert-HKZYKTAIG2ECMXYIBH3HXV4ZBZQ55CLO.pem -u AIDADH4IGTRXXKCD -r i386 -p sampleimage

Here the -r i386 bundled it as 32 bit, while -r x86_64 bundles it as 64-bit. It should ask you which one you want if you don't specify it and have a default option (I believe it defaults to 64-bit).

Comment: I just looked at my command line again -- and I definitely specified -r i386

Answer (score 0):

I was using the EC2 console from Amazon.
Looks like it was just a bug with Amazon.

When I came back this morning it worked fine.